# Play multiple audio files from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, audio

I have images and audio files stored in a directory on my server and have the file names stored in my databse table.

I want the audio files to play and pause when a user click on the image associated with the audio file so I created a "Play & Pause" toggle on the images.

The problem I'm having is when I use the toggle it plays the same audio file on each image. It is not playing the audio file associated with the image, rather the first file in the DESC list.

Eample:

- Image 1: plays audio 1
- Image 2: plays audio 1
- Image 3: plays audio 1

Here is my php code:

```
$ringtones = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `ring_id`,`creation`,`ring_name`,`category_id`,`ring_path`, `rt_file` FROM `ringtones` WHERE category_id = 2 ORDER BY `ring_id` DESC ");
foreach($ringtones->results() as $rt){ ?>

<li <?php echo escape($rt->ring_id); ?>>

<a class="mytoggle" style="cursor:pointer;">
<img src="ringtones/rtimage/<?php echo ($rt->rt_file);?>" class="max-img-rt"></a>

<audio id="playaudio">
<source src="ringtones/<?php echo ($rt->ring_path);?>">
</audio>

</li>
<?php } ?>
```

And my JS:

```
$('.mytoggle').toggle(
function () {
document.getElementById('playaudio').pause();
},
function () {
document.getElementById('playaudio').play();
}
);
```

I don't understand why it wont play like this:

- Image 1: plays audio 1
- Image 2: plays audio 2
- Image 3: plays audio 3

Comment: What would `document.getElementById('playaudio')` point to if you have multiple elements with `id='playaudio'`?  The first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the id attribute of your audio elements.  It's never good to have multiple elements with the same id, and you really don't need to give it an id for the simple play/pause functionality.

Then try this jquery code:

```
$('.mytoggle').on('click', function () {
  var player = $(this).parent().find('audio').get(0); // if you restructure your HTML this has to change
  if (player.paused || player.currentTime == 0) {
    player.play();
  } else {
    player.pause();
  }
});
```